# Ideal .NET Architecture?

Tags: architecture

I'm writing this question from the standpoint of an ASP.NET application. However I realize it may be suited to other contexts as well.

There are so many approaches to developing the common elements of an ASP.NET website.  Here are a few I have come across:

- LLBLGen
- SubSonic
- LINQ to SQL
- Entity Framework
- CodeSmith + .netTiers
- NHibernate
- Hand coding DAL/BLL/Presentation

I don't consider myself an expert developer by any means, however I do understand common OOP techniques well, and can get through all my projects just fine.  I do however struggle with knowing how to 'architect' a site.  By that, I mean, should I use 
[n-tier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)?  Is that still the gold standard and the above tools just utilize that concept?  I'm pretty sure I want to hold off on MVC until a future (or final) release.

*****Edit:  I have removed the portion of the question which deals with patterns (singleton, factory) after having more fully understood the separation of the question.  Thank you for all who have answered this part so far, however, my main focus is on the architecture portion.*****

*Edit #2: I changed the title to be more of an agnostic question upon realizing this would apply to more than web-specific architecture.*

---

**Question:** What steps do I take as a first step, when I have sat down in front of a blank canvas (solution file) with all my pre-written documentation and system requirements in hand ? Where do I go from there?

Comment: by the way, your question stands for almost any kind of project - be it web, winforms or web service - and the best answers will also indicate a general architectural approach that will suit any project :)

Comment: Point taken - I have changed the tags and question title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think each of the methods you have outlined has its merits and its downsides. Which you choose will be a matter of personal preference, the experiences of those in your team and the type of project - Linq2Sql is great to get up and running quickly but might not be best suited to a large and/or complex enterprise project for example.. the best thing you can do there is try a few and get to know them.

As for patterns, they help solve specific and recurring problems in a proven way. They also aid familiarisation for developers who didn't write the code. As above, it is worth trying a few to get a feel for what they do and when to use them - but they solutions to specific programming problems rather than architectural patterns.

My typical working process runs:

- Create a logical entity model
- Create the data storage for the entity model
- Create the data access code and business objects
- Create the logic / business layer
- Create the presentation layer

I would typically split Data Access and Business Objects, Business Logic and Presentation (web site / winforms) into their own projects, plus anything that I might want to re-use at a later date also goes in its own project. I also have a Base project containing common extensions and interfaces that I re-use in almost everything I do.

In terms of architecture, I try to ensure my projects are loosely coupled so that you can easily move from a three tier to n-tier architecture easily. Loose coupling also means that you can switch your backing store and all you need to do is write a new Data Access layer with all of your logic and presentation code remaining unchanged.

I think it's important not to get too hung up on **three** versus **n** tier - if you separate your concerns properly extending your system across multiple tiers at later date will not be a difficult exercise.

Comment: Yes - I agree regarding LINQ to SQL.  I have heard that is not well suited to larger applications.  I have delusions of grandeur, so I want an architecture that is robust and scalable.  

Do you feel that 'n-tier' architecture is the best approach?  

Out of curiousity, which approach do you use?

Comment: Terry - thanks for all the input on this.  I chose this answer because of your mention of n-tier and your bulleted steps.  If I could also accept annakata's answer I would also.  Both are excellent and help me understand better.

Comment: LINQ to SQL is a different data access model, don't start thinking that it cannot be used in Enterprise or for big sites.  You just need to work within the problem domain that LINQ is designed to solve.  Stackoverflow is using LINQ to SQL, so its not just for grandma's blog site.

Comment: agreed, the point i was making is that you choose your model based on your requirements..

Answer (score 5):

Such a broad (and good) question. Deep breath.

Not to take away from Design Patterns but they're the tactics compared to the strategy of architecture. Learn them of course, but that's not especially pertinent here.

A lot of the things you mention in the question are not mutually exclusive and could be thought of as sub-strategies for specific sections of the overall architecture. My personal preferences have changed enormously over time and with experience, and I'm still completely naive of some fascinating technology, but fwiw I think there's only one global constant of architecture:

**Separation of concerns**.

This principle is your "gold standard" I think, which informs so many good things: unit-testing, design by contract, dependency injection, MVC, n-tier. I say the first step is to understand SoC and the second is to act on it with test driven development. Everything else I think has pros and cons, but the benefits of maintenance, conception and an architecture driven by recognising the problems first is beyond doubt.

My bookmarks folder is not what I thought it was, but these are some of the online pieces which solidified my opinions on this matter:

- [The importance of SoC](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.59.5311)
- [Intro to TDD](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html)
- [More on TDD](http://www.developerspot.com/tutorials/php/test-driven-development/page1.html)
- [IBM piece on Reference Architecture](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/2774.html)

---

*Edit: where do you start with the blank canvas?*

Add your unit test library of choice and sketch out the tests (aka facts).

**Test > Design > Code > Goto 1**

Comment: Are there resources available out there which more clearly define the SoC?  For example design by contract, dependency injection, n-tier.  Are they consolidated in a reference/book?  Or is this too broad?

Comment: .. of all the means of learning i think i would put books bottom after 1) learning by doing 2) speaking with really experienced developers who know their shit and 3) reading blogs by experienced developers who know their shit :)

Comment: @Terry - couldn't agree more, information is so much easier to digest if it comes in just-in-time bite-size chunks

Comment: I have a habit of trying to hard to get things right the first time instead of just diving in.  Perhaps I spent too much time theorizing the best approach.

Comment: Yeah that'll never work - I've been in a sort of architectural position for 4 years and I'm still writing horrible things which embarrass me 6 months later. Other people are coming up with better smarter ideas faster than I am :)

Comment: I understand that urge kyle, i wrestle with it myself, but the key to improving is making mistakes and learning from them. halfway through almost every project i think about a new/better way to do something next time that i wouldn't have known if i hadn't made the wrong choice the first time :)

Comment: Fair enough - I suppose this question has been rather enlightening for me from more than just an architecture standpoint.  It is still good for me to have a good starting point though (i.e. n-tier or mvc or other).

Comment: the starting point is not design :)

Comment: I do need to know how to organize the classes logically though.  Perhaps I am missing that as the focal point of my question.

Comment: I think you're maybe worrying a bit too much about it :p ..there really is no substitute for getting stuck in, making some mistakes and learning from them - your architectural, design and general project organisation skills will improve with every new project :)

Comment: Did you just link RUP architecture? And not as a .Net/TDD anti pattern. Wauw. Just wauw.

Answer (score 3):

I personally am a fan of the n-tier architecture.  When I start out I will typically create two projects for a web application, the first for the Business Logic and Database access, this is a class library project.  Then I add a web application project for the actual website.

I have in the past built a data access framework that I use that leverages the Microsoft Data Application Block for all data access, and that is what I use to structure all data calls.

I have at times used codesmith or other items, but so far, I've found better luck, just rolling my own code, as I can get more granular with the data.  Granted if I had time to research other ORM tools, I might not need to be concerned about it...

I find that the best approach is typically to create your business objects, data validation and all of the "business" pieces of the application.  Then program in the data access pieces, and finish by putting everything together with the presentation code at the end.  It takes some discipline to be able to do this, but it ensures that you are building things in a manner that can be re-used, and I have had great success.

The book you referenced might be a good example to start with as well.

*Addition from comment*

In response to a comment posted.  Typically inside my Business/Data class library I will use namespaces to separate out the logic from the data.  A few key things are done here.

1. My data method calls are all limited in scope to the assembly, they are NOT items that can be called directly, this way I enforce data access through the business logic for all presentation callers
2. All data input and output is done via objects, rather than DataSets or any other variant
3. The Business methods after validation will call specific methods from the data components to get the needed information.

Comment: How do you seperate your Business logic and DataAccess logic from within the single class library?  Do you create base objects for the DAL and then inherit from them for the BLL?

Comment: Added some detail for you!  (Comments were not big enough)

Comment: When you say "When I start out I will typically create two projects for a web application..." Is this all inside of one project?  Or do you create 2 actual projects, build the first project and reference it as a reference / dll in the web project?  For instance, do you create a new CLASS type project, write your business logic / db layers then build that project and reuse it in your web project?  The reason I ask is I never knew you can have multiple projects within ONE visual studio project ?

Comment: @JonH - Yes, I have 1 VS SOlution with 1 Class Library Project and 1 Web Application Project.  The Web Application Project references my Class Library

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rule out ASP.NET MVC.

The release candidate is due out in January, and surprisingly this time Microsoft seems to be following the true meaning of RC and unless any show stopper bugs are found it will also be made the RTM version.

[Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/12/19/asp-net-mvc-design-gallery-and-upcoming-view-improvements-with-the-asp-net-mvc-release-candidate.aspx)

Comment: I appreciate the input.  I certainly am not ruling it out, and I think it is a great way to approach the site design, however I am trying to commit to using web-forms at the moment for simplicity and go from there.